# Class not found after ajax request - October cms

Tags: ajax, laravel, octobercms

For my application in october cms I'd like to be able to send a mail with the click of a button. I call the php file with an ajax request, however when the button gets clicked I get the error 'class not found' for whichever class I use, doesn't matter which. I already added the file to .htaccess to be able to run it on the button click. I included all classes at the top of the file. Also when I turn it into an artisan command and run it with `php artisan now:send:mail` it works without any issues. I already tried to run `composer dump autoload` and `composer dump autoload -o`. Code is down below, Any idea what I can do to make this work, or in what other way it could be done?

Thanks in advance!

Part of theme.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/plugins/test/notifications/ondemand/OnDemand.php'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

OnDemand.php:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Notifications\OnDemand;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Test\Poles\Components\Metrics;
use October\Rain\Argon\Argon;

class OnDemand
{
    public function send()
    {
        $date = Argon::now(config('app.timezone'))->format('Y-m-d');
        // get some data
        $array = ['date' => $date, 'score' => $score, 'CO2' => $CO2, 'scorecar' => $scorecar, 'scorebike' => $scorebike];
        $email = "test@test.nl";
        Mail::sendTo($email, 'daily.mail', $array);
    }
}

$mail = new OnDemand;
$mail->send();
```

Comment: problem with this is that you are directly using your own `php`. so there is no way for october cms to initialise itself, you are using October cms functinality inside it so its obvious it will not find the classes. probably you can include `autoload file.` BUT bease solution would be add component to plugin which can handle ajax request and then use `OctoberCms ajax framework` to do this.

Comment: reference : https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to do this as part of a custom October plugin you've developed or simply inside a regular October template. However, the absolutely simplest way of having an ajax button to send an email would be as follows:

1) Create a new mail template in the October backend in Settings | Mail Templates

2) In the "CMS" section of October, create a new blank Page

3) For the "Markup" section of the new page, the button HTML:

`<button data-request="onPressButton">Send</button>`

4) For the "Code" section of the new page, the following PHP:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Test\Poles\Components\Metrics;
use October\Rain\Argon\Argon;


function onPressButton()
{
    $date = Argon::now(config('app.timezone'))->format('Y-m-d');
    // get some data
    $array = ['date' => $date, 'score' => $score, 'CO2' => $CO2, 'scorecar' => $scorecar, 'scorebike' => $scorebike];
    $email = "test@test.nl";
    Mail::sendTo($email,'daily.mail', $array);
}
```

That's it. As long as you include JQuery and `{% framework extras %}` in your October page layout, the above will work.

The principal is the same if you're adding this within a custom plugin that you've developed, but the HTML and PHP would obviously go into their individual files within a component if you did it that way.